# Why or what is the need to import unity android games to android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I have experience programming in android studio and new in Unity. I have made a game and was able to ran it in my phone through unity without the use of android studio. So i though to myself that android studio wasn't needed when developing  android games in Unity. But I see some people in the net wanting to import their unity projects to android studio. I got curious and wanted to know why they wanted to do that and if there are any features that android studio can provide that unity cant and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons:

**1**.*Protect Unity project and its code:*

When you perform a contract work that doesn't require you to provide the source code. You can use this to make sure that client has the Android Project only so that they can sign it. With this, client won't have access to the Unity Project and therefore cannot modify or release game for other platforms without your permission. You only release the Unity Project if client paid for that.

**2**.*Embed Unity App in existing Android app:*

When you already have an Android app and you simply want to show the Unity game through your Android app.

**3**.*Gradle*:

When you need to to perform tasks on the Android Project during automated build.

**4**.*ProGuard*:

When you need to obfuscate your code.

There are many other reasons but the ones listed above are the most reasons to export app as Android Studio Project.